# Ubuntu 22.04 on BIOS boot errors during apt upgrade because of grub-efi-amd64-signed

Tags: grub2, grub-efi

I have a remote Ubuntu server running for a few months with no problems. And just now, during an `apt full-upgrade`, I got these errors:

```
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.182~22.04.1+2.06-2ubuntu10) ...
mount: /var/lib/grub/esp: special device /dev/sda15 does not exist.
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 32
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for shim-signed:
 shim-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64-signed | grub-efi-arm64-signed; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64-signed is not configured yet.
  Package grub-efi-arm64-signed is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 shim-signed
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It is odd to me since I am on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS installed on BIOS boot. I figured these should not have worked a long time ago, but they did until now.

```
$ [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS
BIOS
```

I have these drives, only `/dev/sda` is a system drive, with `/dev/sda2` being the `/boot` partition:

```
$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA HGST HUH721010AL (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 10.0TB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: pmbr_boot

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 5      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                        bios_grub
 1      2097kB  17.2GB  17.2GB  linux-swap(v1)        swap
 2      17.2GB  18.3GB  1074MB  ext3
 3      18.3GB  2181GB  2163GB  ext4
 4      2181GB  10.0TB  7820GB  ext4


Model: ATA HGST HUH721010AL (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 10.0TB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  10.0TB  10.0TB  ext4


Model: ATA HGST HUH721010AL (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 10.0TB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  10.0TB  10.0TB  ext4


Model: ATA HGST HUH721010AL (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 10.0TB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  10.0TB  10.0TB  ext4
```

Comment: Run apt-cache policy grub-efi-amd64-signed and see if the package is still in a "phased" upgrade.  I see it at 59% today, slowly increasing, but you can upgrade the packages (the -bin too) yourself directly.

Comment: My problem isn't that the package is held back, but that its post-installation script is failing because it cannot find `/dev/sda15` or something. I never had that partition so I am not sure why it is configured that way in the first place.

Comment: /var/lib/grub/esp is just an empty dir on my system.  Why is there an arm package, grub-efi-arm64-signed , on your amd64 system? Maybe that's messing something up.

Comment: It is not installed, you can even see it written explicitly in the `apt` output.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered exact same problem on my remote server. Same OS version, same problem with the same `grub-efi-amd64-signed` package version.

In my case, I have a RAID'ed drive with BIOS boot. And all `apt` commands except for `apt update` was giving the exact same error:

```
mount: /var/lib/grub/esp: special device /dev/sda15 does not exist.
```

Other resources recommend running `apt purge grub\*` and then reinstalling proper packages, but in my case the purge doesn't work as well.

I ended up removing `shim-signed` and the problematic grub packages via the commands below. Although my understanding is that we don't really need `grub-efi*` and `shim-signed` with a *BIOS boot*, **please be warned that shim-signed is marked as a protected package, therefore removing it might cause further problems on boot up!**

```
# Use with caution!
dpkg --purge --force-all grub-efi-amd64
dpkg --purge --force-all grub-efi
dpkg --purge --force-all grub-efi-amd64-signed
dpkg --purge --force-all shim-signed
```

Afterwards, I've run the `apt upgrade` and `apt autoremove` with no problems, and encountered no problems during/after reboot. Hope this helps...